# How to call controller method by ignoring routes

Tags: ajax, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having these two methods in controller,I want to call GetCountryId from js and pass Id to it but because of routing it always hit Index method,How to solve this problem?

```
[Route("/AutoComplete/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string id, string text, int limit,int? CountryId)
    {
    //Some Code
    return View();
}
public IActionResult GetCountryID(string CountryID)
    {
        //Some Code 
        return View();
    }
```

and the JS Code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get'
    url: '/AutoComplete/GetCountryID',
    data: { CountryID: 100},
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Success!");
    }});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not add `[Route("/AutoComplete/GetCountryID/{CountryID}")]` to the 2nd method

Comment: tried but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing line to

```
 url: '/AutoComplete/GetCountryID/',
```

Answer (score 0):

@StephenMuecke suggestion is really good. Its common problem and routing attributes helps you a lot with solving similar problems. In your case I see few problems.

1. You want to receive string in `GetCountryID` action - you should use int instead of string.
2. You can use routing attributes to solve this question. In your case please add

`[HttpGet("/AutoComplete/{CountryID}")]`

I provide really quick demo here:
[image: Routing attributes demo]
Why you should use this solution instead of your?

1. Its better for other developer to create clear urls to your action/resources.
2. Its really easy to modify and mantain endpoint.
3. I suggest to follow RESTFul guide in case of similar problems. You can read more here : https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9